# Add Custom Attribute to show on Checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, attributes, checkout

I would like to add the custom attribute i created (delivery) to show on the shipping method section of the checkout page.

I have the following code working but when more than one item is being purchased it just lists all the delivery times next to each other. like 3 days 5 days 1 week

```
<?php $cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
          ->getQuote()
          ->getAllItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        $ean = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getAttributeText('delivery');
        echo $ean; 
    }?>
```

I would then want to pull the product name so What im looking for is

Product Name:Delivery Time
**or if multiple items**
Product Name:Delivery Time
Product Name:Delivery Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just do:

```
<?php $cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
      ->getQuote()
      ->getAllItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
    $ean = $product->getAttributeText('delivery');
    $name =  $product->getName();
    echo $name . ':' . $ean; 
}?>
```

Comment: Thank you! it works.. Quick question, it currently lists items as NAME:DELIVERY NAME: DELIVERY. is it possible to add a line break in the code so its in list style?

Comment: This is probably not the best style, (bypassing magento theme formatters), but since it's so simple, I would just output html directly in that foreach. 

i.e.  `echo '<div class="myclass">' .  $name . ':' . $ean .'</div>';` 

or   `echo  $name . ':' . $ean . '<br>';`

Comment: how use i this code to add extra field in check out page ..?@baku